# cp hosts backup/hosts.bak did not work

Tags: shell, unix, user-permissions, cp

I was reading a book on UNIX when I came across this question.
The command

```
    cp hosts backup/hosts.bak
```

did not work even though all files exist. Name three possible reasons.
I could think of one only and that too I am not sure about.
According to me one reason can be the current directory is not writable by the user.
Please help me out to know the actual reasons.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: This was a question in a book. I did not try that on my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `backup/` is not writeable by the user
2. `hosts` is not readable by the user
3. the disk where `backup/` is located is full
4. `hosts` is a directory, not a file